# An element in $(document).ready is undefined in a certain situation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This question comes from

Actually, I was able to find a clue and this is what I found. I have a js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myIdElement = $("#some_id");

  //............
  $.ajax({
    url: getFullUrl(myIdElement.val())
  })
  //..........
```

So when I come to this page from the another page by a link (html link) then `myIdElement` is `undefined`. However, when I reload the page it starts having a proper value. I use turbolinks.

How do I get it to work in all situations?

Comment: var myIdElement = $("#some_id").val();
 try this

Comment: well you shouldnt be getting undefined for your variable... even when jQuery cannot find an element you at least get a jQuery object back.

Comment: And `#some_id` is initially in the DOM when the page is first rendered? Or do you add it via JS later? Also are you sure the [DOM is valid?](http://validator.w3.org/) Also do you know how to use the javascript debugger in your browser? Try to set a breakpoint on that line and look how the DOM looks at that moment.

Comment: @Amit, this was a typo in my code.

Comment: @s1lv3r, yes, it is there initially.

Comment: use var myIdElement = $("#some_id").val(); instead of var myIdElement = $("#some_id");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(document).ready` does not always fire in `turbolink`. Use `page:load` event, instead. On the first page, it fires `ready` event, but on subsequent pages, `document` has always been `ready`, hence no `document ready` event is fired. So, it fires `page:load` to help us.

```
function ready () {
  // Your code goes here...
}

jQuery(document).ready(ready);
jQuery(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myIdElement = $("#some_id");

  //............
  $.ajax({
    url: getFullUrl(myIdElement.val())
  })
  //..........
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: doesn't `(function($) {` itself mean the same as `$(document).ready(`?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp, no it means, a variable is passed as `$` in anonymous function. You are getting it confused with jQuery's `document.ready` shorthand notation which is, `$(function() {});`. See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004129/document-ready-shorthand

Comment: why should `(function($) {` help?

Comment: It will help in cases where other libraries are used and `$` is overwritten. Using this technique, we are safe to use `$`for `jQuery`, even if `$` has been assigned another value.